# Consider heights $AA_1$ and $BB_1$ in acute triangle ABC, prove that $A_1C•BC = B_1C •AC$

Tags: geometry

> Consider heights $AA_1$ and $BB_1$ in acute triangle ABC, prove that $A_1C•BC = B_1C •AC$

This is an introductory problem on Prasolov Geometry but I'm ashamed to admit that I have tried my best but still nothing. I first of all let $P$ be the intersection of the altitudes, then note that quadrilateral $A_1PB_1C$ is cyclic and futher deduced that triangles $B_1BA$ and $CPB$ are similar then took the ratio of their corresponding sides but I got nothing similar to the given problem. I need some hints on on how to attack this problem

Comment: Just checking: 'Prasolov' is just the name of your textbook, but this is still Euclidean Geometry? And presumably $∙$ indicates multiplication?

Comment: Yeah. • indicates multiplication and Prasolov is just the name of the textbook.

Comment: $A_1B_1AB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: @Batominovski, I wanted to use that but how could I be use that Angle $A_1 + A = 180°$?

Comment: Intersecting Chords Theorem

Comment: How do I apply the above theorem to reproduce the desired result.

Comment: $\angle AA_1B=\angle AB_1B=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $AA_1C$ and $BB_1C$ are right triangles sharing $\angle C$, they are similar, hence$$\frac{A_1C}{AC} = \frac{B_1C}{BC}$$ Therefore $$A_1C*BC = B_1C*AC$$

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\cos(\gamma)=\frac{A_1C}{b}=\frac{B_1C}{a}$$

Comment: I would prefer a synthetic method to trigonometric computation on this one.